# If Voldemort died almost 8 years (May 1998) before Scorpius was born (January 2006), why did people think he was the son of Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

If Voldemort died almost 8 years (May 1998) before Scorpius was born (January 2006), why did people think he was the son of Voldemort? Why were there rumors that Scorpius is Voldemort's son?

Also, we know that black hair (Voldemort) is dominant over blonde (Scorpius), and that brown eyes (Voldemort) are dominant over grey (Scorpius), which leads to more confusion as to why there were rumors.

Comment: I heard that Voldemort was dead. Then I heard that he wasn't dead. Then I heard that he was dead again. At this point I don't really know what to believe other than that the Ministry of Magic doesn't know its arse from its elbow.

Comment: **We** know that Black Hair is dominant over Blonde.  However, are Witches and Wizards even *aware* of genetics?  Plus hair dye exists, spells to do the same do too, and Scorpius' second-cousin (Teddy) and first-cousin-once-removed (She-Who-Must-Not-Be-First-Named) were both metamagi, a trait associated with the family of his (Scorpius') paternal grandmother.

Comment: Your genetics argument is oversimplified. Yes, black/brown may be dominant, but two dark haired parents can still have 1 in 4 chance of a blond child if they both carry the recessive gene (heterozygosity).

Comment: Did you miss the fact that Harry Potter has black hair?

Answer (score 1):

This is directly addressed in the play. Time travel is a 'thing' in the Harry Potter universe. The specific rumour is that Malfoy Jr. (a known Death Eater) is infertile and that he used a Time-Turner to send his wife back into the past to allow Voldemort to impregnate her.

> **ROSE:** *That’s putting it mildly. Your mum and dad are Death Eaters!*
>
> **SCORPIUS** (affronted): *Dad was — but Mum wasn’t.*
>
> ROSE looks away, and SCORPIUS knows why she does.
>
> *I know what the rumor is, and it’s a lie.*
>
> ALBUS looks from an uncomfortable ROSE to a desperate SCORPIUS.
>
> **ALBUS:** *What — is the rumor?*
>
> **SCORPIUS:** *The rumor is that my parents couldn’t have children. That my father and my grandfather were so desperate for a powerful heir, to prevent the end of the Malfoy line, that they . . . **that they used a Time-Turner to send my mother back** . . .*
>
> **ALBUS:** *To send her back where?*
>
> **ROSE:** *The rumor is that he’s Voldemort’s son, Albus.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter and the Cursed Child: Official Playscript](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Harry-Potter-Cursed-Child-Playscript/dp/0751565369)</sup></sub>

Like most saucy rumours, there's some grains of truth in the whole thing. Malfoy *did* have trouble getting his wife pregnant and Voldemort *did* (allegedly) sire an heir with female Death Eater. The problem is that people have added two and two and come up with five. Right father, wrong mother.

> **HARRY:** *If you answer the gossip, you feed the gossip. There’ve been rumors Voldemort had a child for years, Scorpius is not the first to be accused. The Ministry, for your sake as well as ours, needs to steer well clear.*